# Facet-wrapped x-axis with vertical lines around each level

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have this plot with multi level x-axis:

```
Years <-  c("2016","2016","2016","2016",
           "2017","2017","2017","2017")
Quarters <-  c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4",
        "Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
Series1 <- c("100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800")
Series1 <- as.numeric(Series1)

df <- data.frame(Years,Quarters, Series1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
        geom_point(aes(x = Quarters, y = Series1)) + 
        facet_wrap( ~ Years, strip.position = "bottom",scales = "free_x") + 
        theme(panel.spacing = unit(0,"lines"), strip.background = 
element_blank(),
              strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image: Current R Chart]

I am wondering if ggplot would allow me to add lines around the groups to look like this :

[image: Excel Chart]

Comment: Not easily. You could build the axis in grid, but it's a lot of bother.

Comment: @alistaire the goal is to move our excel based reporting to R so that it is automated.  Continuity and seeing the exact same reporting is key to my stakeholders.  I will read upon grid.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: for your own sanity, I strongly advise you to stick with `ggplot2` and instead focus on convincing your stakeholders that these new plots are improved and even better than the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Its not lines like you requested but this is close:

```
Years <-  factor(x = c("2016","2016","2016","2016",
            "2017","2017","2017","2017"), 
            levels = c("2016", "2017"))
Quarters <-  factor(x = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4", "Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"), 
                    levels = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"))
Series1 <- c("100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800")
Series1 <- as.numeric(Series1)

df <- data.frame(Years,Quarters, Series1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Quarters, y = Series1)) + 
    facet_wrap( ~ Years , strip.position = "bottom",scales = "free_x")
```

[image: testplot1]

Comment: This I have as well, but the goal is to recreate excel charts on R and automate the process.  Thanks for help.